# Whenever I add datatable in React function component, showing such alert message

Tags: reactjs, datatables

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#transporter").DataTable(

      {
        "ordering": false,
        scroller: true,
        language: { search: '', searchPlaceholder: "Search...", sLengthMenu: "Entries per page _MENU_" }
      }
    );
  });
```

[image]

Comment: The pop-up message you show in your screenshot gives you a link: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3. Did you read the information in the linked page? It provides an explanation of the general problem, and different ways for you to try to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#transporter").DataTable(

      {
        "ordering": false,
        scroller: true,
        bDestroy: true,
        language: { search: '', searchPlaceholder: "Search...", sLengthMenu: "Entries per page _MENU_" }
      }
    );
  });
```